# Simple pathes in an acyclic graph

Tags: graphs, dynamic-programming

How to answer on many requests by type:

> Count amount simple paths passing through chosen edge in an acyclic undirected graph using dynamic programming?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: Please mention if the graph is directed.

Comment: No, unfortunately, graph is undirected.

Answer (score 1):

Since the graph is acyclic, we know that it is a forest - which means that, there is at most $1$ simple path between two nodes. Now, simply root the graph at one vertex of the edge, remove the edge, and run a dynamic programming algorithm to find the number of vertices in the subgraph, call it $v_a$. Similarly, do the same for the other vertex of the edge, call it $v_b$. The answer is $v_a*v_b$, since the simple path between every $2$ nodes is a different simple path.

Proof: Clearly every simple path we consider passses through the chosen edge. The only other simple paths are the ones where both the nodes are chosen in the same subgraph, which clearly does not pass through this edge.

Comment: @Maxim, am I missing something for this answer to be accepted?

Comment: Looks fine to me. It's a stretch to call "counting the vertices" a DP algorithm, but I suppose if you squint...